# computing the Koopman modes using the Arnoldi Algorithm

Tags: matlab

I have a state matrix `A(m*m)` and i want to generate the Krylov subspace (I will use it later in computing the Koopman modes) , so i found in matlab help this command: `B= Gallery('Krylov',A,X,j)`, where `j= m`, the question here is how can i choose the vector X, in some articles they choose it as a random vector but it does not make sense to me because everytime i choose a random vector all the results will change.

I want to insist that i want to compute Koopman modes using Matlab.

Thank you